# Partial Order set equation and element

Tags: discrete-mathematics

b) Determine whether each of the relations defined below on the set of positive integers is a partial order?

(a)  (x,y) ϵ R if x = y2 
(b)  (x,y) ϵ R if x > y 
(c) (x,y) ϵ R if x   y 
(d)  (x,y) ϵ  R if x = y 
(e) (x,y) ϵ R if 3 divides x-y

Comment: Try first the simple ones, like (a) and (b), applying the defintion of [Partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition).